# Populating a struct list in different voids

Tags: c#, list

I have a quick question about adding items to a new list  So I have the following code:

```
Public struct testType
{
    public string title
    public string names
}

public List<testType> testlist= new List<testType>();

private void readTitles(string line)                                                                             
{
    string[] substrings = line.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    testType temp = new testType();
    if (substrings.Length > 0)
        for (int i= 0;i<substrings.Length;i++)
        {
            temp.title= substrings;
            testlist.Add(temp);
        }
    else
        temp.title= "";
}

private void readNames(string line)                                                        
{
    string[] substrings = line.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    testType temp = new testType();
    if (substrings.Length > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)                                       
        {
            temp.names= substrings[i];
            testlist.Add(temp);
        }
    else
        temp.names= "";
}
```

So it can be seen that testlist will get populated with both the titles and names. It will populate with the titles and with names being null.Then names being populated with titles being null.  How can I add the names to the created list without adding a new line to testlist with null values?

Comment: Apologies but I'm confused on this question.  You're making a new ```testType``` and adding it to the list.  What are you expecting to happen?  If you want to add the titles and names then I suggest doing it all in the same loop or replacing the existing struct with a new one that includes already present information.  The problem is, unless the lists are kept in perfect order, you can't predict which title is associated with each name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are reading the titles and names in separate methods?

An obvious solution is to just read both at the same time within the same method, then you can create a single testType instance with both properties populated. I am assuming there will always be the same number of titles as there are names, and that the ordering in the strings is predictable:

```
public struct testType
{
    public string title
    public string name
}

public List<testType> testlist = new List<testType>();

private void readData(string titlesLine, string namesLine)  
{
    string[] titles = titlesLine.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] names = namesLine.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
    {
        testType temp = new testType();
        temp.title = titles[i];
        temp.name = names[i];
        testlist.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

EDIT: An alternative (but less recommended) approach. If you really can't/won't combine the two methods into one, you can call them separately, and write the code as shown below, provided that you always call readTitles before readNames, and you always supply the data in the same order each time.

```
public struct testType
{
    public string title
    public string name
}

public List<testType> testlist = new List<testType>();

private void readTitles(string titlesLine)  
{
    string[] titles = titlesLine.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
    {
        testType temp = new testType();
        temp.title = titles[i];
        testlist.Add(temp);
    }
}

private void readNames(string namesLine)
{
    string[] names = namesLine.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 0; i < testlist.Count; i++)
    { 
        testlist[i].name = names[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have to have to read the titles and names separately.

Comment: @jas really? What's the reason? Are you sure you can't amend the code which calls on this method slightly? If you're unsure, perhaps show that dependent code so we can understand.

Comment: I am reading a file and manipulating a lot of data with it and need to keep everything separate.  The main file is 1000+ lines so its not easy to show I just added the lines necessary to understand my problem

Comment: @jas " need to keep everything separate"...this is an assertion without justification (at least, none that you've given to us) IMHO. Need is based on the requirements as well as keeping things tidy on the screen. Code can always be refactored to be nicer, but in the end you have to get the job done as well. Is there a _technical_ reason why it's not possible, or is a bad idea? If you don't pass in the titles and names at the same time, how do you propose to associate them together efficiently?

Comment: @jas I guess if you really want to keep separate methods, and if you always do titles and then names, and the data's always in the same order, the names loop could just amend each existing testType object in the list and add a name to it, and assume it got the right one.

Comment: its file converter to convert different file types.  To make the conversion its best to have the data in precise voids.  Could you detail more how I could amend each existing testType object in the list and then add a name to it.  That is exactly what I would like to do.  Also titles and names will always be the same size.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  It is greatly appreciated

Comment: " its best to have the data in precise voids"...I have very little idea really what you mean by this. Can you expand on this opinion? What do you mean and why is it "better"? You seem to have two simple lists of titles and names in string fields, you want to make them into a structured object, which is sensible. The obvious approach is to send both sets of data to the same method for processing. I cannot grasp your objection to this, other than a stubborn unwillingness to alter some other code which depends on it, and/or a (mis)understanding of something else you haven't clearly described.

Comment: @jas I very _strongly_ suggest you listen to ADyson.

Comment: @jas I have added an alternative approach as you requested, but really you should not need it.